# windows.h not found, although included in path

Tags: windows, compilation, mingw

I am trying to compile a program under Windows. This fails when including `windows.h`. This file is located in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include` and I have modified the PATH variable:

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27;
...
;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\tools\cscope\;
C:\Program Files\KDiff3\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git;
C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw32\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw32\libexec\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.2;
C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

Somehow this header file is still not visible, either for `windres`, `cmake`, `gcc`, etc. Is there some environment variable that I need to set or do I have to add the include directory everytime I compile a program?

Comment: The PATH environment variable is used to find executable files, not include files.  Your INCLUDE environment variable is out of whack.  LIB will probably be next.

Comment: @HansPassant, while what you say about `PATH` and header files is correct, references to `INCLUDE` and `LIB` are not helpful here. `<windows.h>` is a standard system header in _any_ Windows C/C++ compiler tool chain, so if the tool chain is correctly installed and configured, this header should be present, and found implicitly (relative to `PATH`). That it is not suggests an installation or configuration fault; correction of such a fault does __not__ involve tweaking `INCLUDE`, or `LIB`, (or any of GCC's other auxiliary search path specific environment variables).